# R - ggplot - jitter plot with transparent data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I want to get a jitter plot with transparent data points and I use this code:

```
p<-ggplot(house_data,aes(x=cloudCover, y=solar_energy, color = day_night)) 
p<-p+geom_jitter()
p<-p+geom_point(alpha = 0.01)
p
```

I get a jitter plot but unfortunately I do not get transparent data points. I experimented with different values for alpha but the plot stays the same... What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `ggplot(<as as above>) + geom_jitter(alpha = .01)` should work too.

Comment: it would be helpful to have some sort of example data. I'm guessing `cloudCover` and `solar_energy` are discreet and `day_night` is categorical / binary? What are you trying to achieve? To call `geom_points` and `geom_jitter` on the same data does not make sense to me, as one is better suited for a discreet y-axis (`geom_points()`) and one for categorical data (`geom_jitter()`).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem @randomchars42. And you are also right regarding the types of the variables. The first comment solved the problem :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `position_jitter` in the point geometry.  The `width` and `height` parameters are the amount of jitter on the x- and y-axes respectively:

```
p<-ggplot(house_data,aes(x=cloudCover, y=solar_energy, color = day_night)) 
p<-p+geom_point(alpha = 0.01, position=position_jitter(height=.5, width=.5))
p
```